# LinuxOSにおけるネットワークの設定について

Tags: network, dns

今まで、フリーのドメインを使っていたのですが、今回ドメインを購入して利用することにしました。
今までは、固定IPではない(自宅サーバーであったため)定時間隔ごとにcurlでIPアドレスをDNSに登録していたのですが、
外部からAWSのWEBサーバーに有料ドメインを使ってアクセスしようと思ったのですが、
/etc/~配下のネットワーク設定ファイルというのは、LAN内に限られた設定で、外部に公開するためのドメイン設定、DNS設定はドメインを購入した側でするものなのでしょうか？

お恥ずかしい質問ですが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: AWSのWEBサーバーのIPのAレコードを登録するのは質問主さんのネームサーバーです。WEBサーバも自宅サーバも関係ないとおもいます。（もちろん、理由があればするに越したことはありませんが、それはつぎの段階）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

まず、あなたが購入したドメインを管理するDNSサーバを用意してください。たいていのドメイン業者は無償のサービスで提供してると思います。AWSであればDNSのサービスとしてRoute53がありますのでそれを使ってもよいです(有償ですが)。自分のサーバにBINDをインストールするという選択肢もありますがあまりお勧めしません。

用意したDNSサーバに必要なリソースレコードを設定します。ホスト名→IPアドレスの変換をするAレコードとか、メールの配送先を設定するMXレコードとかです。

そして、そのDNSサーバのIPアドレスを上位(購入したドメインがexample.comなら.comドメインの、example.co.jpドメインなら.co.jpドメインの)DNSサーバに登録します。これは(普通は)ドメインを購入した業者がやるのでそこに頼みます。ドメインの管理画面にそんな項目があるでしょう。

･･･と言うように、自前でDNSサーバを運用する場合を除いて、名前解決される側のサーバでやることはありません。

サーバ側でどのようなホスト名を設定しようが、DNSでの名前解決に関係ありません。全然別の名前を設定していても、極端な話、名前解決される側のサーバは実在しなくてもDNS上は何の影響もありません。

(まぁサーバ側の動作には支障が出てくる点もあるので普通は一致させますが)

Comment: ありがとうございます。

> 名前解決される側のサーバでやること

これは、結局内向きのみの設定になるんですか？
結局Linuxサーバーでhostnameの変更などはなんの意味があるのでしょう？

Comment: 内向きというのはLANの設定のことだと思いますが、LANも同じドメインで運用したいということなら、LAN上にプライベートDNSを立てて、プライベートで見つからないホストはパブリックDNS（この回答のDNS）にフォワードするように設定することも可能です。パブリックDNSだけで運用することも不可能ではありませんが、プライベートIP(192.168.XXX.XXXなど)を登録するのはセキュリティ上好ましくありません。

Answer (score 2):

VPS やクラウドサーバーには、直接グローバルIPアドレスを設定するものと、プライベートIPアドレスを設定してサーバーの外側で変換(NAT)するものがあります。

AWS の EC2 は後者で、サーバー(EC2インスタンス)にはプライベートIPアドレスが設定されます。グローバルIPアドレスはサーバー起動時に自動で割り当てられるもの(可変)か、Elastic IP (固定)を付けます。これは、サーバー内の設定ではなく、AWS 側の設定です。

このグローバルIPアドレスとサーバー名、ドメイン名を紐付けるよう、DNSサーバーに設定します。DNSサーバーは Route 53 を使ってもいいですし、他でもかまいません。

ドメインのレジストラ側の設定で、ドメイン名と DNSサーバーを紐付けます。

Answer (score 1):

ご質問の環境がAWSということですので、ネットワーク環境のVPCについて概要を掴まれることをおすすめします。

VPCは閉じたネットワーク内にEC2を配置して、Public IP (または EIP）をEC2インスタンスに与えることで、アマゾンのネットワーク機器上で アドレス変換（NAT）され インターネットとの接続を可能にします。

DNS名前解決については、Route53を使えば、Private DNS としても使えますし、AWSのサービスとの親和性も高いので 特に理由がなければ 公開DNS もRoute53がおすすめです。

公開するドメイン、VPC内の閉じたドメイン、何方も名前解決できれば EC2 側は `/etc/hosts` に自分自身のエントリーを書くくらいだと思います。